# Updating a column using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

My table has two ID fields (I did not put 2 IDs so dont ask me why). One is a primary key and the other is a nullable duplicate field which will contain the value of the primary key itself.

```
public static void UpdateDuplicate_ID(Company updatingCompany)
       {
           Company tempCompany;

           using (var context = new TestLiveDataContext())
           {
               tempCompany = (from company in context.Companies
                             where company.Id == updatingCompany.Id
                             select company).FirstOrDefault();

               tempCompany.DuplicateId = updatingCompany.DuplicateId;

               context.SubmitChanges();
           }
       }
```

It seems the above code is not working. I can't update the duplicate id with my primary key value. Can anyone tell me whether I am missing anything here?

Comment: How do you know it isn't working? How are you checking?

Comment: Cant see the id updated in the database...

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on the assignment in order to check that you are in fact assigning it the correct value?

What is the point of the method out of interest? If duplicateId should always be the same as Id there are much better ways to enforce this.

Comment: Also, any chance we can see the code for you calling this method?

Comment: Service.UpdateDuplicate_ID(newCompany.Id);

Comment: You pass in the id? In this case why does your method expect a Company object?

Comment: I have already done that now.Passed in the id instead of the company object..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10706/discussion-between-kingcronus-and-josh)

Comment: @KingCronus Thank you for your time... Appreciate it...

Comment: This is my new code...                                            var tempCompany = context.Companies.Single(x => x.Id == intupdatingCompanyID); 

               tempCompany.DuplicateId = intupdatingCompanyID;

               context.SubmitChanges();

Comment: If you're using the Entity Framework, you need to mark the entity as being modified, before calling `SaveChanges`, for the changes to persist.  Like so: `context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(testCompany, EntityState.Modified);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as I can see, `updatingCompany` and `tempCompany` appear to be the same record.

If this is the case, you may be overwriting the chance outside of this method if you later change the value passed in and save again.

Does beg the question, why don't you just change the value in `updatingCompany` and then submit changes on its own context, rather than starting up a new one?

That is unless I have misunderstood the problem.